# Is this proposition true? $P(n):: n^2+(n+1)^2$ is either a prime number or a perfect square $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

$P(n):: n^2+(n+1)^2$ is either a prime number or a perfect square $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

For this problem we assume that $0 \notin \Bbb{N}$.

I've tested P(n) to see what happens by plugging in up to $n=5$. It seems to be true but I'm having trouble proving it so any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to prove P(n) by induction in the following way:

**Base case:**

$P(1):: 1^2 + (1+1)^2$ is either a prime number or a perfect square.

$1^2 + (1+1)^2 = 1 + 2^2 = 5$ which is prime.

**Inductive hypothesis:** We assume P(n) holds for n.

$P(n+1):: (n+1)^2+(n+2)^2$ is either prime or a perfect square.

So we have:

$(n+1)^2 + n^2 +4n+4$ is  a prime or a perfect square.

By our hypothesis we have that one of the following holds:

**(i).** $(n+1)^2 + n^2 $ is prime

**(ii).** $(n+1)^2 + n^2 $ is a perfect square

Assuming **(ii)**:

For some $m \in \Bbb{N}$, $(n+1)^2 + n^2 = m^2$

Therefore we can express P(n+1) like this:

$m^2 + 4n + 4$ is either a prime or a perfect square

So if P(n+1) is not true, $\exists a,b \in \Bbb{N} \text{ \ } \{ 1; m^2 + 4n + 4\}$ such that $a \ne b$ and $ab = m^2 + 4n + 4$

**And maybe we can find a contradiction here???**

Assuming **(i)**:

In this case I'm even more clueless.

Would it help to write P(n+1) as:

$m + 4n + 4$ is a prime or a perfect square, assuming m is a prime number??

**Edit:** Many users have commented that it is not true and that I should try more examples, and indeed, $6^2 + 7^2 = 85 = 5*17$. P(n) is not true for all n. I feel a little stupid for not trying one more n now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Intuitively that can't be true. Try more values.

Comment: Well, you have $36+49=85$

Comment: There are definitely $n$ for which this is neither a prime or perfect square. Just try some more numbers.

Comment: Try $n = 6 $ and  $n = 10$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculating for $$n=6$$ your formula $$n^2+(n+1)^2=2n^2+2n+1$$ and this gives $$72+12+1=85$$ is not a square number and not a prime number

Answer (score 1):

The smallest counterexample is $6^2+7^2=85$.